# Function moving on before AXIOS promise response is returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, https, axios

I am having a problem with the responses of this function. The function is supposed to return a concatenated list of all ITEMID for a game. This list can change depending on what is being sold at a time. The first axios call is used to grab the first 1000 item numbers and the number of pages. I would then have to make axios calls for the amount of pages to retrieve all of the item numbers. Seems a bit tedious but I don't think there is a way around this.
The problem is the function isn't running the other pages and only returns the first 1000 items before the other responses come back. Is there a better way to implement this function?

```
    export const getAllItemID = (region) => {

    let finalList = [];
    let pages = 0;
    let currentPage = 1;
    let region_buy_id = `URL For Call`;

    axios
        .get(region_buy_id)
        .then(json => {
            pages = json.headers['x-pages'];
            for(let k in Object.values(json.data)){
                finalList.push(json.data[k]);
            }
            currentPage++;
        })
        .then(()=>{
            while(currentPage <= pages) {
                let region_buy_id = `URL For Call`;
                axios
                .get(region_buy_id)
                .then((json) => {
                    for(let k in Object.keys(json.data)){
                        finalList.push(json.data[k]);
                    }
                });
                currentPage++;
            }
        })
        .then(()=>{
            return finalList;
        });

}


Updated Function 


export async function getAllItemID(region) {

    let finalList = [];
    let pages = 0;
    let currentPage = 1;
    
    let region_buy_id = `URL`;

    await axios
        .get(region_buy_id)
        .then(json => {
            pages = json.headers['x-pages'];
            for(let k in Object.values(json.data)){
                finalList.push(json.data[k]);
            }
            currentPage++;
        });
    while(currentPage <= pages) {
        let region_buy_id = `URL`;
        await axios
        .get(region_buy_id)
        .then((json) => {
            for(let k in Object.keys(json.data)){
                finalList.push(json.data[k]);
            }
        });
        currentPage++;
    }
        

}
```

Comment: This is tbe reason async await was created. Nested promise chains are troublesome because they're hard to read, leading to bugs like the one you have. Try converting to async and await. Your issue is that you are not chaining the second axios call to the first.

Comment: Ok I had tested it with that before and it did work. Does this seem like the proper way to do this type of code? I also posted with the "answer."